# Can I use Sharkbite fittings to split vanity sink supply lines?

Tags: plumbing

I’m trying to convert my vanity into a double vanity but it only has the one set of hookups. I bought Sharkbites. Would I just need to cut the pipe and add attachments to connect? I don’t care about code just as long as it works.

[image]

Comment: If by "hookups" you mean the hot and cold water supply to the faucet(s), we will need to see a clear picture of the stop valves (the valves that those old copper tubes are connected to).

Comment: **A)** What are "saw shark bites"? **B)** "I don't care about code" - yes, yes you do. If you don't then your sink probably won't drain correctly - that's what code ensures. It will cost more (time & money) to fix it than it will to do it right the 1st time. Also, when you go to sell the house (you do own, correct?), there will be an inspection which you'll fail, and you'll have to fix it then (more difficult, more expensive), or reduce the sale price so the purchaser has funds to fix it (more expensive). Otherwise, yes, just cut pipe & add attachments.

Comment: Are those copper hard lines?

Comment: Sharkbite fittings are UPC and IPC conformant, so no code issue. By their literature the lifespan is 25 years compared to 50 to 100 years for copper pipe. Compression fittings are superior to sharkbites and require only wrenches to install. Have you considered compression fittings?

Comment: There are rubber o-rings in the sharkbites, so I imagine that burs will wreck them (I'm only imagining--I would never use sharkbites for permanent plumbing). You would cut the copper tube, but be sure to sand the edge smooth before installing a sharkbite fitting.